# TailwindCSS - can't figure out padding

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this component, and neither px or pl is working, i can't figure out why.

```js
const TopNav = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <header className="fixed border-b-2 w-full h-[--navbar-height] bg-white">
      <nav className="px-10">
        <div className="pl-10 flex h-[--navbar-height] justify-between items-center">
          {children}
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default TopNav
```

if i add `style={{ padding: '0 2rem' }}` to the nav or the div it behaves as expected

[image]

Comment: What part of the code you're showing is TailwindCSS?

Comment: what do you mean? it's all in the classnames

Comment: Is the padding actually in the CSS when you inspect the elements?

Comment: I mean there's no way for anyone to replicate what you're doing with TailwindCSS.... that  code looks like React?

Comment: it is react code, but all the classNames are Tailwind and they work, except the `p-` or `p-l`

Comment: I'm sure it makes sense to you, but it would really simplify things from a StackOverflow perspective if you could provide the output code where the issue is happening.  The screenshot doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: Rowan's question is unanswered but still relevant.  "Is the padding actually in the CSS when you inspect the elements".

Comment: no, the padding isn't in the CSS, but i don't know why, all the other classes are being reflected in the CSS....

Comment: And in the HTML, does it definitely have `px-10` etc in the class attribute? If so, that implies that maybe Tailwind is pruning that CSS for some reason 

Comment: @RowanFreeman and if not, it's not a Tailwind issue at all.

Comment: it does have the `px-10` attribute, but it doesn't reflect in the Styles

Comment: "maybe Tailwind is pruning that CSS for some reason", why would it do that?

Comment: No idea! Tailwind works by scanning your classes during a build step and then only including what it finds. It removes all other CSS classes so that it ships only the minimum possible CSS.

Comment: Have you included `@tailwind base`, `@tailwind components` and `@tailwind utilities`?

Comment: yes, all three of the includes

Comment: Consider checking the file the code is in is covered by the content file globs and that `10` exists as a value for `padding`.